# SQLite error no such column using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sqlite

I am trying to track down a bug that only appears on some clients machines and of course we can not reproduce the error in house. The `InnerException` thrown is

> SQLite error no such column: Extent1.UserDefinedPid

The column that can not be found is a bit field defined thusly in the SQLite database:

```
[UserDefinedPid] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

The EDMX file contains this definition (just partial contents):

```
<EntityType Name="Parameter">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="ParameterID" />
  </Key>
  <Property Type="Int64" Name="ParameterID" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
  ...
  <Property Type="Boolean" Name="UserDefinedPid" Nullable="false" />
  ...
</EntityType>
```

We have confirmed the same SQLite database file and proper `System.Data.SQLite` and `System.Data.SQLite.Linq` dlls are being loaded but for some bizarre reason some machines seem to think this column is missing.

The database we are using is encrypted and we have an app.config file for the application the make sure other installs of SQLite do not interfere with the application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections></configSections>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0 - 2.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.66.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I am out of ideas as to why this fails on some machines. Any ideas are greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: What's the name of the column? Anything interesting about it, e.g. does it contain accented characters?

Comment: @JonSkeet The name of the column that is throwing the error on some machines is UserDefinedPid. Nothing particularly interesting about it other than the fact that it fails on some machines but not others. The offending machine is running Windows 7 Professional SP1 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that you are using a [quite old version](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) of System.Data.SQLite.

Perhaps you can give a try to the latest version found [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).

Once you do that, the app.config file will not be needing this anymore:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0 - 2.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.66.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>
```

I'm a bit unclear about the encryption concerns you mention. Are you encrypting with the password provided to the `SQLiteConnection` connection object, or are you using the [SEE extension](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html)?

Comment: We are using version 1.0.66.0 which is from April 2010. We tried to use the latest build 1.0.81.0 on the problem computer but it just immediately crashed and could not open the connection at all (think it was an error loading the data provider). We are using RSA encryption on the database to protect our IP. There is not a concern about the encryption but if there is a chance that might cause an issue I wanted to make sure I noted that fact.

Comment: @BrianWenhold: my take on this would be to figure out the problem with the new version and use it instead before going any further with the problem(s) you have right now; perhaps start a new question if need be.